# three.js custom attributes

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl, three.js

I'm trying to make a real-time in-browser shader writing tool and I have a problem with custom attributes. You can see what we've got here: 78.46.211.78/index.html

The vertex shader and fragment shader windows are self-explainable, as is the final render. The interface channel is a piece of code that gets executed every frame before rendering, so that our changes can be made therein. Now, in the interface channel, we can define attributes, uniforms and variables (Javascript global variables) by right-clicking and choosing the appropriate option. When making new attributes or uniforms, input them in the form of [type] [name], where type is "f", "v3", etc.

This will add the attributes and uniforms to the hash of attributes and uniforms attached to the material (a new material is created with every change to the shaders).

Another thing I want to warn about front on is the shortcuts that I've implemented: A is the hash of attributes, U are uniforms, J are variables, O are objects in the scene.

Here's how to recreate my problem: right-click the interface channel window, choose to add a new attribute, at the prompt type "f displacement". This creates a new attribute float value in the vertex shader as well as a piece of aux code in the interface channel, something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < O.sphere.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
  A.displacement.value[i] = 1.0;
}
A.displacement.needsUpdate = true;
```

Now, go to the vertex shader and change this:

```
attribute float displacement;
void main() {
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
  modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

into

```
attribute float displacement;
void main() {
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
  modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,displacement);
}
```

...and it won't work. All the source code needed is visible on inspection. I've checked the references - the material does reference the arrays needed. I never once saw the needsUpdate = true come to effect, though. Errors in the console will show up because compilation of code will happen as you type, but once you finish the sentence, these will stop, so don't get frightened.

Comment: Can't seem to access that URL you provided.

Comment: yes, sorry about that, we've been having some problems in the last two days. It should be working now. Sorry, again.

Comment: I have to say that it's strange - if I shred down everything except a very basic sample of custom attributes (as the one in the three.js examples), it works perfectly fine. Is there any known limitation to the initialization of materials? Should the attributes, by rule, be defined strictly before something else in the system, maybe?